# Embed PApplet intp JApplet

Tags: java, applet, processing

How can I embed a `PApplet` into a `JApplet` ?
I wanted to add it to a `JPanel` inside the `applet`, but I couldn't.

If any of you know how I can do this. ??

Comment: What sort of code/approaches have you researched and/or tried already?

Answer (score 1):

Prior to Processing 3, this code should have worked for you as @Kevin has explained. So, if your question is directed towards understanding a legacy code here is what you will need to know:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class MyPApplet extends PApplet implements ActionListener{
    @Override
    public void setup() {
        super.setup();
        // setup
    }

    @Override
    public void draw() {
        // my draw code
    }
}

public class PAppletDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("PApplet in Java Application");
            JPanel panel = new JPanel();

            //create an instance of your processing applet
            final MyPApplet applet = new MyPApplet();

            applet.init();
            panel.add(applet); // From processing 3, this will give you error that applet is not a Component

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(applet.getSize().width, applet.getSize().height +200);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

To circumvent this, you will need to use PSurface getNative() function. Please refer to the [example and discussion given on this link](https://forum.processing.org/two/discussion/12260/processing-3-init-disappearance).

Answer (score 0):

As of Processing 3, you can no longer do this. `PApplet` no longer extends `Applet`, so it can't be treated as a component.

For 95% of users, this is okay. Applets are dead anyway, so you really shouldn't be using them. If at all possible, you should try deploying with Processing.js.

If you need to execute a Processing sketch from Java code, then you should use the `PApplet.main("YourSketchNameHere");` function to launch it. Processing will take care of the window for you.

If you really need to treat a `PApplet` as a component, then you're going to have to go through its `PSurface`. The `PSurface` class contains a `getNative()` function that returns an object that can be treated as a component. But that's overkill for most Processing users.